# iCloud Private Relay MITM Defense?

Tags: vpn, proxy, apple, icloud

When it comes to defending against MITM attacks while using public Wifi, is the security offered by iCloud Private Relay comparable to using a VPN?

Edit:

My motivation for asking the question comes from the PDF overview published by Apple. In it they say:

“It’s built directly into the networking framework of iOS, iPadOS, and macOS, and protects traffic most susceptible to tracking: web browsing and any connections that are unencrypted. As a result, Private Relay protects all web browsing in Safari and unencrypted activity in apps, adding both privacy and security benefits.”

https://www.apple.com/privacy/docs/iCloud_Private_Relay_Overview_Dec2021.PDF

Obviously that protects Safari from MITM attacks. But my question is more specifically does Apple’s description imply that all traffic, including system network connections and app network connectIons, is protected against MITM attacks on public Wi-Fi?

Comment: iCloud Private Relay is a VPN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iCloud Private Relay is a VPN. It uses an encrypted tunnel to send requests from your device to Apple servers, and from those servers to the endpoint server that in turn sends the request to the internet.

If you are interested in protecting your Safari traffic against a public wifi operator, or people using the same wifi, the level of protection of a VPN and iCloud Public Relay are the same. Both encrypt the traffic before it leaves the device, and the endpoint access the internet in your behalf.

The main difference between the two is that a VPN works system-wide: all traffic from all apps are routed to the VPN unless explicitly excluded, while iCloud Private Relay currently only works inside Safari.

Comment: Does it only apply to Safari or is there some level of protection for the other apps / system components?

Comment: It's not system wide. It only protects you while using Safari. All other apps will use your default connection.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: It only protects DNS, HTTP and HTTPS connections, does not encrypt anything else.

Comment: @ThoriumBR private relay is *not* a VPN at all. It's a set of proxies with encrypted dns. https://www.apple.com/privacy/docs/iCloud_Private_Relay_Overview_Dec2021.PDF

Answer (score 1):

iCloud relay is implemented as a double proxy with "oblivious" encrypted DNS over https according to [Apple's Private Relay Overview](https://www.apple.com/privacy/docs/iCloud_Private_Relay_Overview_Dec2021.PDF).

> When Private Relay is in use, the user’s device opens up a connection to the
> first internet relay (also known as the “ingress proxy”). The software for the first
> internet relay is operated by Apple in locations around the world.
> As the user browses, their original IP address is visible to the first internet
> relay and to the network they are connected to (e.g., their home ISP or cellular
> service). However, the website names requested by the user are encrypted
> and cannot be seen by either party.

> The second internet relay (also known as the “egress proxy”) has the role
> of assigning the Relay IP address they’ll use for the session, decrypting the
> website name the user has requested and completing the connection. The
> second internet relay has no knowledge of the user’s original IP address and
> receives only enough location information to assign them a Relay IP address
> that maps to the region they are connecting from, conforming to the IP Address
> Location preference they selected in Private Relay settings. The second internet
> relay is operated by third-party partners who are some of the largest content
> delivery networks (CDNs) in the world.

The secure DNS described above would decrease the risk of MITM attacks like DNS spoofing for some use cases, however there are added risks the end user should consider.

**Benefits and Caveats for the Common User**

For everyday use cases, the end user should compare Apple's service quality and stance on privacy against that of their local ISP. Providers like Verizon, T-Mobile, Comcast Xfinity, Charter Spectrum, AT&T and Google Fiber were reported to have [troubling data collection practices](https://www.cnet.com/home/internet/ftc-calls-out-internet-providers-for-amassing-user-browsing-data/). Enabling private relay helps to prevent data collection by hiding the user's requested domain and IP resolution.

That being said, there is implied trust in Apple to avoid collecting and selling user web traffic profiles. Google [lied about tracking users incognito](https://www.reuters.com/legal/google-settles-5-billion-consumer-privacy-lawsuit-2023-12-28/), and Apple could arbitrarily deactivate the *oblivious* nature of their relays when they need to. With visibility into user domain resolution, it opens the opportunity to collect and serve analytics tied to the user -- including incognito traffic (again looking at you Google).

It is unclear how Apple is required to comply with government requests for user information. There is no publicly available statement regarding Private Relay and gov requests. If asked to comply, they may be required to collect data on relayed requests.

**Opt-In Security Risks with Apple Services**

With private relay opt-in by default, Apple implicitly subjects end users to vulnerabilities in three additional steps of web resolution (including MITM among others).

With [heart bleed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartbleed) and [Kaminsky's bug](https://duo.com/blog/the-great-dns-vulnerability-of-2008-by-dan-kaminsky) poking holes in core ISP DNS providers, and Apple's history of [reported web service vulnerabilities](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201536), users must trust Apple's ability to patch and maintain zero-days in a timely manner. Without published audit compliance or SLA's, **security-focused use cases should avoid using private relay** and use a provider with published security audit requirements. A brief test shows Akamai is one of the underlying DNS providers private relay uses, which does not support or comply with DNSSEC audit requirements.

**End-User Device Risk is Unchanged**

It's unclear *how* Apple provides encrypted dns and proxy addresses, but **the most obvious way to MITM private relay is the same without private relay** -- DNS spoofing. If a spoofed DNS resolved a malicious IP for a domain, private relay will blindly service traffic to the IP. Here's how an encrypted DNS spoof could be done for an Apple device (with or without private relay):

- Spin up a malicious DNS server which resolves names to a malicious endpoints
- Apply and register for a HTTPS certs
- On the malicious DNS server, provide encrypted DNS over HTTPS with the acquired certs
- Create a signed secure dns device profile ([like these for google dns, cloudflare, etc](https://github.com/paulmillr/encrypted-dns))
- Install the device profile on a targeted Apple device, which will override all dns lookups (caveats).

Other common DNS attacks still apply but are no different with or without private relay. After resolving an IP, traffic is still proxied either way. Examples include:

- Modifying the user's `/etc/resolv.conf` with a different dns
- Modifying the user's `/etc/hosts` with different host ips
- Modifying the user's iptables with different destinations for resolved ips

**Added Risk with Public IP Gateways**

Similar to VPN exit nodes, private relay implicitly subjects the user to hidden risks with public IP grouping. Examples include:

- High security websites like banks will have difficulty detecting the user's login anomalies when a bad actor is routed through the same relay as the user.
- Security firms tracking malicious entities (e.g. money laundering) collect source IP data. The user could be subjected to scrutiny if frequently routed through the same relay exit as bad actors.
- Services using IP Geolocation will provide misleading location evidence to law enforcement agencies, like in the [2023 FBI Carpenter v United States case](https://www.wired.com/story/fbi-purchase-location-data-wray-senate/).